# How to do a stratified random sample in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to take a random sample of customers who have purchased from different categories. There are 8 categories, and orders are spread among them.

If I wanted to take a random sample of customers who have made a purchase, but keep the proportion of orders per category the same, how would I set that up in my sql code?

A table highlighting this is below (it doesn't include customer data - I want my list of customers to be based of the representative proportion of orders):

table that I am using can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIeVE.jpg

Comment: Postgres or Redshift. Although they share they same roots they are quite different.

Comment: Postgre sql running on Reshift!

Answer (score 7):

Basically, you would use `row_number()`, `order by`, and choose the nth values.  So, for about a 1% stratified sample, do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by category, rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where mod(seqnum, 101) = 1
order by category;
```

The basic idea is that you can get a stratified sample by ordering the result set by the categories and doing an nth sample of the result.

Comment: Hey Gordon, do you mean I run that query for each category?

Comment: Not sure on what you mean Gordon. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: @nz426 . . . No, that would be a silly way to get a stratified sample.  This query get an approximate 1% stratified sample.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what is the reason for 101 instead of 100? Also, thank you for your answer.

Comment: If your version of SQL doesn't have the `mod` function, you can do `where seqnum % 101 = 1` instead.

Answer (score 5):

@Dnoeth solution is effective and easy to use. But, please change rand() into random(). AWS redshift's random function name is 'random'. Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_RANDOM.html. 'random() works for me but not rand()

```
select *

from
(
 select t.*
  ,percent_rank()
   over (partition by category
         order by random()) as pr
from tab
) as dt 
where pr <= 0.1 -- similar to 10% sample
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a `PERCENT_RANK` over random order to get a n% sample oforders:

```
select *
from
 (
   select t.*
      ,percent_rank()
       over (partition by category
             order by rand()) as pr
   from tab
 ) as dt
where pr <= 0.1 -- similar to 10% sample
```