# how to retrieve certain percentage of orders from a field?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

sample
[image: a01 b02 c03]

How to retrieve only 5% of order_ids from this field? Please consider the field has 10k+ values.

select 5% order_id
from table

Comment: You want to select about 5% of the rows of a table? So, if the table contains only three rows, you would select zero rows? What is your DBMS?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which 5% do you want? The top 5%? The bottom 5%? Random? What determines top or bottom?

Comment: the field has more than 10,000 rows and I want to select only 5%

Comment: random 5% should do

Comment: Check if your DBMS supports a SAMPLE syntax

Comment: We are all waiting for you to tell us which DBMS you are using. Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: it is redshift. sorry for keeping you wait

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NTILE`, which you must apply in a subquery in order to be able to use it for filtering.

```
select order_id
from (select order_id, ntile(20) over () as n from mytable) tiled
where n = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a completely random sample you can use `random()` function that returns a decimal between 0 and 1:

```
select * from orders where random()<0.05
```

there are other ways to get samples like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154325/how-to-do-a-stratified-random-sample-in-redshift)